# What is the term for PIE a, o > PGmc a merging?

Tags: proto-indo-european, proto-germanic

PIE **a**, **o** > Proto-Slavic **o** has a name  "Квантитативное выравнивание" ?quantity alignment?
Does PIE **a**, **o** > PGmc **a** have a special term?

Comment: I want to say no, since I've never heard of a special name for that, but I'd never heard of a special name for the Slavic case either.

Comment: I’ve never heard of a special name for the Slavic merger either – I doubt it’s in use outside Russian/Slavic languages. Perhaps the same term is used for the Germanic merger, which is after all very similar to the Slavic one except mirrored: short _*a, *o_ becomes Gmc. _*a_ and Sl. _*o_; while long _*ā, *ō_ becomes Gmc. _*ō_ and Sl. _*ā_. But in English, I don’t believe there’s a more specific term than ‘the merger of non-high back vowels’.